# Erro ao buildar para android ionic

Tags: android, linux, ionic, android-studio, ionic3

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> BUILD FAILED in 0s /home/flavio/helloworld/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/home/flavio/helloworld/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
>     line: 68
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
>
>   > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess
>   cordova.
>
> ```
>     cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
>
>     Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
>     information.
> ```

Eu possuo o android-tools instalado, é necessário realizar mais alguma configuração?

Comment: A versão do `Android build tools` está correta? 19.1.0 ou mais nova? Você executou o comando, como sugere o texto, de maneira verbosa para conseguir mais informações sobre o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi esse problema editando o arquivo

> ..\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle

no método `getAvailableBuildTools()` alterei a linha que cria a instância de File.

**De:**

```
def buildToolsDir = new File(getAndroidSdkDir(), "build-tools")
```

**Para:**

```
def buildToolsDir = new File("d:\\Acacio\\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\\tools\\build-tools")
```

**Aponte para o build-tools da sua máquina**